# how can combine two neighbour site(cell) in voronoi diagram?

Tags: merge, cell, delaunay, voronoi

How can I combine two neighbour site(cell) in `voronoi diagram`?
I decide in my project combine two neighbour site(cell) in `voronoi diagram`, can any one help me?

Comment: What's the problem with just deleting the edge that separates them?

Comment: This sounds like a coding issue / representation issue or definition issue, not algorithmic issue. If that's a coding issue - what's your data structure? If that's a definition issue, what are your requirements on the operation?

Answer (score 0):

The dual Delaunay triangulation can be represented by a much simpler data structure. You can mark those triangle edges which are dual to the Voronoi edge you need to remove as invalid.